# Spy wake up on lan packages

Tags: networking, wakeonlan, tcpdump

I have a windows computer which trunes on by magic I had long time no clue why this happens until I found the command `powercfg -lastwake` which told me that my NIC woke up the computer. The wired part is that I did not send a WOL package. So I want to know the source. Here comes the linux part:

Do you guys know a way to collect only WOL packages? I think that is possible with tcpdump, but I'm not sure how I can filter WOL packages and how I can run this on my RaspberryPi as a deamon. Do you have an idea how to achieve that? In best case I would like to have a log file which contains the source/target MAC and the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my own solution I'm running this command in a `screen`:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 '(udp and port 7) or (udp and port 9)'
```

For logging I combined that line with the `-x` flag and `tee`. So my full solution is this here:

```
$ screen
$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 '(udp and port 7) or (udp and port 9)' -x | tee wol.log
```